# Change the position of <li> on keyup event

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list.
I got to know how to get the index of an li tag using jquery.
What i want to do is change the index of li tag i.e if i press 'c', the li tag having the text starting from 'c' should be shown first. And then the rest of them.

Is it possible?
If yes, how?

## edit 1:

This is the function that is called on keyup event:

```
function displaySearchResult(key){
              var li=$('.listcontainer ul li:contains('+key+')');
              li.parent().prepend();
          }
```

But i think it will work only if i type the entire text as key.

Please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: and what have you tried? where you got stuck provide the code plz then someone will try to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us say you've selected your desired list item and stored it in the variable `li`:

```
li.parent().prepend(li);
```

Comment: Here I sat, thinking about sorting algorithms. You sir just saved me a couple of precious minutes and deserved an up with an ingenious, effective solution. You should apply for president.

Comment: @TimS. I actually sort of overcomplicated it. You don't need to detach the element, jQuery does that for you.

Comment: Here i have used `:contains(key)` which gives me the li that contains the key value anywhere in that text. How to get the li that starts with the key value?